# Automate Login to site using Spring Boot (Spring Security) and LDAP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I am working on a Spring Boot project, which uses LDAP in Spring Security for authentication.

I need to automate the login once the user hits the login page based on the roles in LDAP group provided in Spring Security.

If user has any role in the group mentioned in LDAP, then it must redirect to the corresponding page after login. (i.e page1 in my example).

I have been searching 2 days in a row for this for any online documentation or an example, but in vain. All I could find is using a jdbcDataSource or hard coding the username and password in Controller and later validating it when login or through Spring using web.xml. But not via LDAP. Any help would be much helpful.

**This is how my Spring Security XML looks**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/webjars/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/page1" access="hasAnyRole('GP1','GP2')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/page2" access="hasAnyRole('GP1','GP2')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/page3" access="hasAnyRole('GP1','GP2')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />

        <form-login default-target-url="/page1" login-page="/login"
            always-use-default-target="true" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403.html" />
        <csrf disabled="true" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        erase-credentials="false">
        <authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <ldap-server id="contextSource" url="ldap://url"
        manager-dn="mymanagerdn" manager-password="mymanagerpswd" />

    <beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean id="bindAuthenticator"
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <beans:constructor-arg value="myDCvalues" />
                <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
                <beans:property name="ignorePartialResultException"
                    value="true" />
                <beans:property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(member={0})" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userSearch"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0"
            value="myDCvalues" />
        <beans:constructor-arg index="1"
            value="(sAMAccountName={0})" />
        <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
        <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

**My WebController**:

```
package com.myPackage;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Controller
public class WebController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/page1").setViewName("page1");
        registry.addViewController("/page2").setViewName("page2");
        registry.addViewController("/page3").setViewName("page3");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/403").setViewName("error/403");
    }

    @GetMapping("/page1")
    public String page1(HttpSession session) {
        return "page1";
    }

    @GetMapping("/page2")
    public String page2(HttpSession session) {
        return "page2";
    }

    @GetMapping("/page3")
    public String page3(HttpSession session) {
        return "page3";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/403")
    public String error403() {
        return "error/403";
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    private String getCredentials() {
        String credential = null;

        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        credential = userDetails.getUsername().toString();

        return credential;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your convenience, this answer comes with a [complete and working sample](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/tree/b21c56d7614132503ef42a95ba9ac5b2fdcd8b8c/samples/boot-ldap-example), including an LDAP server, populated with users and groups and an integration test, so that you can run these tests yourself.

Assume you have the following user in LDAP

```
dn: cn=marissa,ou=Users,dc=test,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: marissa
userPassword: koala
uid: 20f459e0-e30b-4d1f-998c-3ded7f769db1
mail: marissa@test.com
sn: Marissa
```

The username is *marissa* and the password is *koala*.

Let's start with the test case:

```java
    @Test
    @DisplayName("ldap login works")
    void doLogin() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login")
                .param("username", "marissa")
                .param("password", "koala")
                .with(csrf())
        )
            .andExpect(status().is3xxRedirection())
            .andExpect(authenticated())
        ;
    }
```

From this test, we can deduce that

1. LDAP uses form login, username/password
2. The form has CSRF protection

So let's configure your Spring Boot application using Java config

The classic sample file, `SecurityConfig.java`

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

The security configuration doesn't change.

1. We want users to be fully authenticated
2. We want to use form login

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
        ;
    }
```

That's it, next we configure LDAP, again in your `SecurityConfig.java` we do this by calling the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. This is a bean that Spring Security configures. So we can access it using `@Autowired`

```java
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldap://localhost:389")
                    .managerDn("cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com")
                    .managerPassword("password")
                    .and()
                .userSearchBase("ou=Users,dc=test,dc=com")
                .userSearchFilter("cn={0}")
                .groupSearchBase("dc=test,dc=com")
                .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
        ;
    }
```

and that's it. Now, I used some code I wrote from the Cloud Foundry UAA project to create an in [memory LDAP server](https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community/blob/b21c56d7614132503ef42a95ba9ac5b2fdcd8b8c/samples/boot-ldap-example/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/community/samples/ApacheDSHelper.java) for my integration tests.

So when the mock MVC integration test starts up, it starts an LDAP server to run against.

It really is that simple. You can now expand this sample to map LDAP groups to Spring Security authorities.

The LDAP Sample is available in my community repo: https://github.com/fhanik/spring-security-community.git